# Xcode/ios: Core Data Prepare for segue error with topViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am trying to follow an excellent [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-nsfetchedresultscontroller--cms-21681) on Core Data on Tuts plus and NSFetchResultsController.  The prepare for segue method, however, is throwing an error.  Here is code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addToDoViewController"]) {
        // Obtain Reference to View Controller
        UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        AddToDoVCViewController *vc = (AddToDoVCViewController *)[nc topViewController];

        // Configure View Controller
        [vc setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }
}
```

Specifically, the UINavigation line is fine.  The following line starting with AddTo..., however, gives 5 errors in red:

```
Missing '[' at start of send expression
Expected ']'
Use of undeclared identifier 'vc'
Expected expression
Use of undeclared identifier 'AddTodoVCViewController'
```

The next line after Configure View Controller gives red error:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'vc'
```

Have checked spelling of files etc. at this point am pretty much stuck.  Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried building the project even with the errors?  Sometimes it takes building the project for the compiler to recheck for errors.  Or perhaps there is an extra brace somewhere above the code?  Or maybe an extra bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is OK. Check for unbalanced `[]` or `{}`, and try to perform a clean with
<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: Correct for checking code ok.  Turned out problem was I forgot to import  AddToDoVCViewController.